# How to connect SharePoint Online listview webparts using connected webparts with "less than" conditions

Tags: listview, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list EmployeeMaster which has Employee, designation and supervisor details. My requirement is to filter the list view based on the logged-in user designation details. For example, if I am a manager then I want to see the employees of the supervisors who are in the manager level as well as employees of the junior level supervisors. Created a column LevelNumber where I store numbers for each level. D=1, AD=2, SM=3, M=4, SA=5 etc ...

Tried using connected web parts, where 1st web part is added to filter with Supervisor=[Me] so that I will get my LevelNumber (my idea is to get the supervisors who are less than or equal to my level number) and  2nd web part is connected with a level number of 1st web part. Now am getting supervisors who are at the same level of mine but not able to get the junior level supervisors.

Is there any way where I can filter using LevelNumber less than or equal to my level number through connected web parts.

I have tried all the filter web parts and works only for the equal conditions. Anyone, please help. OOTB way.

Comment: Is that in classic experience? If so, you can edit the page in SharePoint Designer and change the query filter in the code.

Comment: i don't have designer installed . also it's not in classic .

Comment: How can you use filter web parts if it's not classic? Please explain in more detail what modern web parts you use for the filter.